# What happens when running Django server on pythonenywhere.com?

Tags: server, localhost, hosting, pythonanywhere

As [pythonanywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com) is the one of best place to host python web app. And apps will be hosted as per `wsgi.py` configurations on it's own server. But what happens when I do something like this on its **bash shell**?

```
$ python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:9000

Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 28, 2016 - 15:29:48
Django version 1.9.5, using settings 'MyProject.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:9000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

As you can see I had changed the port to `:9000`, so is there any way to access this or it's just meaningless as it's **serving the app on served server service**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PythonAnywhere dev here.  There's no way to access a server you run using `manage.py runserver`.  It will try to bind to a local port, but that port isn't visible from outside the PythonAnywhere cluster.

[edit] Oh, and thank you for the kind words about PythonAnywhere!

Comment: That means it's just meaningless. So probably it's going to consume CPU cycles so why PythonAnywhere devs allows user to that? I mean they can do something that prevents users to host on that port like this way. And I think I found perfect man to ask. @Giles Thomas

Comment: Yup, it's meaningless, but it doesn't consume much in the way of CPU cycles-- I'd guess less than one second to start up, then nothing.  We could block people from binding to ports generally, but we couldn't do it for Django only -- and there are various obscure packages that can actually usefully bind to a cluster-only port/IP address (some scientific stuff in particular).  It wouldn't be possible to allow them but disallow Django (or Flask or other web frameworks with a local test server).